# save to csv in datatables

Tags: jquery, csv, datatables

I have a table. In the table, last column contains only two images, By using datatables I save the table's record in csv form. But I want to exclude the last column, as it contains only 2 images, from the csv file. HOw to do that. Please help me. I my code is like:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
   "oLanguage": {
       "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
       },
   "oTableTools": {                     
       "aButtons": [{
                     "sExtends": "csv",
                     "sButtonText": "Save to CSV"
                     }]
   },
   "aoColumns": [
       null,
       null,
       null,
    { "bSortable": false }, // disable the sorting property for checkbox header
    null,
    null,
    null, 
    { "bSortable": false } // disable the sorting property for checkbox header
       ]
} );
```

Comment: I got the answer. By making use of mColumns:[0,1,2,3,4] I got the result. But still in the csv file, I dont want the last table row which is in tfoot tag. So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

By using the column defaults it migh tbe possible to do this by making the column not visible.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
    "bSearchable": false,
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [4]
}]
```